# SSIS 2015 can't create Data Sources

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ssis

Our admins have installed SSIS 2015 on our server.

However, when we open a previous solution (made with Data Tools 2010) we see that all the connections aren't found:

[image]

If we try to make a new connection, this is the error that pop-ups:

[image]

Any ideas on how this is happening and how to fix this? On the server there is still installed Visual Studio 2010 (and our solution hasn't been upgraded when opened with Visual Studio 2015).

Thanks

Daniele